# Why is the `#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` code greyed out?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, win-universal-app

I am building a Windows Universal app. In the `App.xaml.cs` file directives are used to separate code that targets the Windows Phone 8.1 store from code that targets Windows desktop store:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
```

However as I develop I see that the code for the active project, the Windows Phone 8.1 project, is greyed out.

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Why?

How to I nudge Visual Studio into realising that the `#if WINDOWS_APP` code should be greyed out and the `#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` code should be rendered normally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is greyed out in the image because you are in the context of the Windows app -- look at the left-most drop-down just above the code window, where it says `Things.Windows` -- this sets the context to the Windows app. If you change the drop-down to `Things.WindowsPhone` then it will switch contexts to the Windows Phone app.

The bolded item in the Solution Explorer just indicates which app will run when you hit F5; it doesn't determine what the active context is.